# FusedLocationProviderClient - Bad accuracy

Tags: android, android-gps, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm getting a very bad accuracy with FusedLocationProviderClient and PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY.

Example of Locations returned (I'm stoped, i'm not moving).

```
Location[fused 38,993027,-1,871872 hAcc=7 et=+4d9h38m28s50ms alt=734 vel=0.01439964 bear=180.0 vAcc=2 sAcc=2 bAcc=180 ]
Location[fused 38,992887,-1,871716 hAcc=8 et=+4d9h38m41s51ms alt=734 vel=0.07460203 bear=180.0 vAcc=2 sAcc=2 bAcc=180 ]
Location[fused 38,992943,-1,871938 hAcc=7 et=+4d9h39m40s674ms alt=73. vel=0.2066238 bear=324.07718 vAcc=2 sAcc=-1 bAcc=-1 ]
Location[fused 38,993088,-1,872128 hAcc=6 et=+4d9h40m17s336ms alt=734 vel=0.15840407 bear=0.0 vAcc=2 sAcc=3 bAcc=88 ]
Location[fused 38,993200,-1,872311 hAcc=6 et=+4d9h40m24s401ms alt=734 vel=0.040956344 bear=0.0 vAcc=2 sAcc=-1 bAcc=-1 ]
Location[fused 38,993256,-1,872534 hAcc=6 et=+4d9h40m42s344ms alt=734 vel=0.006034331 bear=0.0 vAcc=4 sAcc=2 bAcc=98 ]
```

If PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is the best option for tracking purpose. Why lat,lon are so diferent respect the previous locations if i'm at the same place, stopped?.
[image]